# Write JSON file with X and Y axis

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a requirement to write my JSON output as **[{"x": "MaxTemp", "y": "Temp3pm"}]** and my current output looks like [MaxTemp, Temp3pm], so the logis here is, as per the screenshot the first word is X_axis and the second word after comma(,) is y_axis. Below is my code and I have attached the screenshot of the input data.

```
x_y_data = list(selected_ri['index'])
x_y_data

ini_string = {'Imp_features_selected_x_y':x_y_data}

# printing initial json 
ini_string = json.dumps(ini_string)

# converting string to json 
final_dictionary = json.loads(ini_string)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use str.split to split text by ',' and expand into two columns, for example:

```
df = df['index'].str.split(',', expand=True)
# then rename column name to x and y 
df.columns = ['x', 'y']
```

then you can convert it into a dict and output as json at last

```
data = df.to_dict('records')
ini_string = json.dumps(data)
```